# Remove "MIME type" column from Filent Content List

Tags: dojo, ibm-content-navigator, ibm-case-manager

I am Using a Script Adapter by passing payload to get contend for a **Content List** from "Search with values" event

[image]

When Contend get loaded to content list , i have a custom view to preview them. But if i clicked on MIME type column , It opens a separate view with the mapped viewer

So I need to remove this column or make it un-clickable

1)  I am passing search values to content list's "Search with values" event , from where can i handle Content List's contend loading ,any Dojo Event i can use ?

2) With Script Adapter can i do this without going for a "response filter"

Edit :

As Nicely explained by "Ivo Jonker" (in his answer - "or try to specifically locate the widgets on your page" and with his example code)

```
responsed = page.ContentList8.ecmContentList.getResultSet();
var cols = responsed.structure.cells[0];
        for (i=cols.length-1; i>0; i--){
            var col = cols[i];

            if (col.field=="mimeTypeIcon")
                cols.splice(i,1);
        }
page.ContentList78.ecmContentList.setResultSet(responsed);
```

I simply remove this row. Thanks Again and lovely blog , hope you keep posting more great articles.

Comment: Any chance the widget-configuration "Open documents in a new viewer" - or the disabeling of the icm.OpenDocument broadcast influences this functionality?

Comment: I have remove "Open documents in a new viewer" and have remove icm.OpenDocument broadcast and it didn't help , This only happened when I click On "mime Type Icon" . seems it do a publish event and opens image in separate viewer(New Browser window) with mapped view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The values passed  through the Search With Values event will eventually be handled by the icm.pgwidget.contentlist.dijit.DocumentSearchHandler 
   that in turn creates a SearchTemplate to execute the search (ecm.model.SearchTemplate.prototype.search). One option would be to aspect/before/around the DocumentSearchHandler#query to manipulat the searchresults and by that way to remove the column.
2. The wiring however does not provide any handles to achieve this for a specific query-resultset combination leaving you to either fix this on a global scale (icm.pgwidget.contentlist.dijit.DocumentSearchHandler.prototype#query), or try to specifically locate the widgets on your page.

Personally, taking into account #2, i'd go for the responsefilter-option if you feel the global solution wouldn't be a problem, or alternatively i'd personally prefer to create a simple ICM widget that instantiates/implements a "plain" ecm.widget.listView.ContentList and exposes a wire to set the ecm.model.Resultset.

You'd then be able to create your own Searchquery in a scriptadapter, remove the column, and pass the resultset.

The script adapter could be something like:

```
var scriptadapter=this;

var queryParams={};
    queryParams.query = "SELECT * FROM Document where id in /*your list*/";
    queryParams.retrieveAllVersions = false;
    queryParams.retrieveLatestVersion = true;
    queryParams.repository = ecm.model.desktop.repositories[0];
    queryParams.resultsDisplay = {
        "sortBy": "{NAME}",
        "sortAsc": true,
        "columns": ["{NAME}"],
        "honorNameProperty": true};

    var searchQuery = new ecm.model.SearchQuery(queryParams);

    searchQuery.search(function(response/*ecm.model.Resultset*/){
        //remove the mimeTypeIcon
        var cols = response.structure.cells[0];
        for (i=cols.length-1; i>0; i--){
            var col = cols[i];
            if (col.field=="mimeTypeIcon")
                cols.splice(i,1);
        }

        //emit the resultset to your new contentlist, be sure to block the regular synchrounous output of the scriptadapter
        scriptadapter.onPublishEvent("icm.SendEventPayload",response);

        //The contentlist wire would simply do contentlist.setResultSet(response);
});
```

Comment: Jonker first thanks for your detailed reply , 1) aspect.after seems i good option ,so how i get aspect.around to get called when this DocumentSearchHandler.prototype#query event called (how can i listen to this Globe event's changes , any wire i can run this) ? any place i can read on DocumentSearchHandler.prototype's static methods